# Sublime Text 2 doesn't open SumatraPDF anymore

Tags: pdf, latex, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I installed [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) many months ago on my Windows 7 machine. Everything worked fine even two days ago. Now, all of the sudden, Sublime Text 2 won't open SumatraPDF anymore after compiling (Ctrl+B). I didn't change anything on the system. Of course, the LaTeX document compiles without any errors or warnings.

Using the command prompt

```
SumatraPDF path-to-pdf-file
```

still opens the according pdf document in SumatraPDF. Even inverse search works as long as I open the corresponding pdf document manually in SumatraPDF.

Do you have any idea what could be the reason for that problem and how to solve it? What shall I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click on Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package settings > LaTeXTools > Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings

Comment: Thanks. Somehow everything worked fine today without any adjustments. So I didn't reset my configuration.